# configuring cisco switch sg-300 20 can't change vlan name

Tags: cisco, switch

I have this very strange issue.  Not a biggy because I can do it using the GUI but it still drive me nuts.  Just out of curiosity whether anyone has been through this and know the answer to it.  It's actually very simple.  What I'm trying to do is to create a simple vlan and add name to that vlan.  Nothing special.  I can use this standard IOS command on my Catalyst 3560.

```
enable
conf t
vlan 10
name New Vlan
end
```

simple right?  However when I tried to use the same command on my SG300-20, it doesn't work.

```
enable
% Unrecognized command
```

Ok so I ignore "enable" and go straight to configuration terminal

```
conf t
vlan 10
name New Vlan
% Unrecognized command
```

Can't do it?  Very strange.  Again, it's not a biggy but I'm more curious to learn whether there's actually a different IOS language that I need to learn.  Using GUI is nice but documentation for me is such a pain more than just a command line.  Anyone would like to take a stab on this and help me learn a new trick?  Please advise?

Comment: The command reference guide shows you how to do this (VLANs / Name).  While there are many similarities, the SG300 devices do NOT run the same IOS as a Catalyst.  You shouldn't expect the commands to be identical.

Comment: Wow. To whoever voted this question down, please help me understand why? I'm trying to learn and voting down without explanation doesn't really help anyone to learn. I spent couple of days trying to figure out how to change simple name via CLI and couldn't figure it out thus I posted the question. If you were not willing to help, don't help, but don't be a dick either.  This is one among many reasons why I hesitate posting on serverfault because of the concern with respond from people like you.

Comment: I helped and I downvoted.  I didn't realize I needed to be super specific and explain that I downvoted because you haven't bothered to read the manual.  It took me 20 seconds to find the correct answer and I've never touched one of the things.

Comment: I didn't vote, but votes are anonymous, and explaining a vote removes the anonymity. People, including you, are entitled to vote how they want with no explanation. I would imagine, but do not know for sure, that the down votes are because you didn't even try to research this as Cisco has many documents explaining how to configure your device.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Yoonix. I wasn't expecting the CLI to be same just as I wasn't expecting command line for CentOS to be same like Ubuntu even though both are linux. I was asking for anyone who has done it to share the information if they have one.   I found the answer to my question btw. Here is how they do it.

```
conf t 
vlan 10 
int vlan 10 
name New Vlan 
end
```

Goodness gracious Cisco..